# jquery - how to close div

Tags: jquery, html

I have button that open div with form.

how do i close the box when use click on ".fa-times"?

index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300 } );
});
</script>
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="st-actionContainer left-bottom">
    <div class="st-panel">
        <div class="st-panel-header"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-times pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
        <div class="st-panel-contents">
            Some text
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="st-btn-container left-bottom">
        <div class="st-button-main"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the jquery script:
https://github.com/dlenhart/st-action-panel-git/blob/master/js/st.action-panel.js

Comment: do you need animation of removing this div or want to remove this div immediately.

Comment: better without animation....

Comment: just tell your 3 method call anyone to your `fa-times`

Comment: *call ---- (tell)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** To remove the div you can use `.remove()`, but you can't access the div later.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div").remove();
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:black;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button >click me</button>
```

**2.**
There is other way to remove the div, use `.hide()` it will hide the div that's why you can access div later.

```js
$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("#div").hide();
});
$("#show").click(function(){
  $("#div").show();
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:black;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button id="hide">click me to hide</button>
<button id="show">click me to show</button>
```

**3.**
This can be done by `.toggle` function.It will hide and show the div.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div").toggle();
});
```

```css
div{
  background-color:black;
  width:300px;
  height:200px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div"></div>
<button >click me</button>
```

Comment: but this script has already have function that close the div - closePanelAnim. how do i run it when i click on "fa -fa-times">